# How does JPA knows how to link columns and entities with join-table?

Tags: java, xml, jpa, orm

Totally noob at JPA, I got this:

Three tables:

[image]

Also, a orm.xml file which describes their relationship:

```
<one-to-manyname="nombreAtributo"fetch=" {LAZY}">
 <join-table schema="NOMBRE_SCHEMA" name = "TABLA1_TABLA2">
      <join-column name="TABLA1_ID" referenced-column-name="ID" unique="true"/>
      <inverse-join-column name="TABLA2_ID" referenced-column-name="ID"/>
  </join-table>
```

(This snippet is inside its Tabla1 entity tag).

All right. The idea is having a list on TABLA1 of TABLA2 elements, so we "tell" through the ORM.xml file "Hey, nombreAtributo (in TABLA1) is the result of going through the TABLA1_TABLA2 relationship. TABLA1_ID is related to ID and TABLA2_ID to ID.

I get that what I'm actually saying is "TABLA1_ID is related to TABLA1.ID and TABLA2_ID is related to TABLA2.ID", but I fail to understand how JPA knows it. Is for the kind of relationship defined? For the names?

(And yeah, we are using xml's instead of annotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is written in the javadoc of [JoinTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) :

**Annotation Type JoinTable**

> Specifies the mapping of associations. It is applied to the owning side of an association.

So, according to the below xml mapping for `TABLA1` entity, the entity which owns the relation is `TABLA1` :

```
<one-to-manyname="nombreAtributo"fetch=" {LAZY}">
 <join-table schema="NOMBRE_SCHEMA" name = "TABLA1_TABLA2">
      <join-column name="TABLA1_ID" referenced-column-name="ID" unique="true"/>
      <inverse-join-column name="TABLA2_ID" referenced-column-name="ID"/>
  </join-table>
```

**joinColumns**

> (Optional) The foreign key columns of the join table which reference
>   the primary table of the entity owning the association. (I.e. the
>   owning side of the association).

So, the join-column `TABLA1_ID` reference the PK of **TABLA1** since `TABLA1` owns the association.

**inverseJoinColumns**

> (Optional) The foreign key columns of the join table which reference
>   the primary table of the entity that does not own the association.
>   (I.e. the inverse side of the association).

So, inverse-join-column `TABLA2_ID` references the PK of **TABLA2** since `TABLA2` doesn't own the association.

Comment: Thanks! Thanks to the use of xml's instead of annotations, everything is a bit harder to find. Just in case someone finds this, the Javadoc you mention seems to be this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html

Comment: you are welcome. Totally right, with annotations, the javadoc assistant in your IDE is very helpful and allows to learn quickly. I edited my answer to add the javadoc link